# How to search a collection using childrenByXPath?

Tags: javascript, alfresco

The collection has 4 values (A, B, C, D) and any combination can be selected in the document.

Trying to mach for only (A, B).

```
var nodes = space.childrenByXPath("\*[@cm:mychoice='A, B']/\*");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var nodes = space.childrenByXPath("\*[@cm:mychoice='A' or @cm:mychoice='B']/\*");
```

should do the trick.